# How to crawl a web page for files of certain size

Tags: python, web-crawler, filesize

I need to crawl a list of several thousand hosts and find at least two files rooted there that are larger than some value, given as an argument. Can any popular (python based?) tool possibly help?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how you can get the filesize of an file on a HTTP server.

```
import urllib2

def sizeofURLResource(url):
    """
    Return the size of an resource at 'url' in bytes
    """
    info = urllib2.urlopen(url).info()
    return info.getheaders("Content-Length")[0]
```

There is also an library for building web scrapers here: http://dev.scrapy.org/ but I don't know much about it(just googled honestly).

Comment: Yes, I also figured this out. One idea I have is to parse all "a href"-s from the main page (i already wrote a tool that does that) and continuously read the http header information to find pages/files of appropriate size. If  no such are found, repeat the parsing on the list of pages obtained at the previous step (do this for a depth of say 5, also checking that you don't process anything that already has been processed). I think that's pretty simple and theoretically it should work. Maybe I don't actually need all the functionality of a dedicated web crawler/scraper.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it. See the code below.

```
import urllib2
url = 'http://www.ueseo.org'
r = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print len(r.read())
```